# Bootstrap scrollable tab pane with a dropdown menu gets cut off

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a scrollable bootstrap nav tab by making the `tab-pane` css be this:

```
.tab-pane {
    height:300px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

I have a bootstrap drop down that is configured to have the menu pop up and the menu is getting cut off. My dropdown code is:

```
<div class="btn-group dropup">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Action</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span class="caret"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Wondering if there is a solution to this.

http://jsfiddle.net/jqntuxvf/3/

Answer (score 0):

You can add additional `padding-top` in `tab-pane` class so the drop down menu have some space

Here is edited fiddle from yours http://jsfiddle.net/jqntuxvf/13/